# Linux rm command with variable

Tags: linux, scripting, rm

My partners and I are having troubles with this basic Linux script. Our instructor dumped an advanced Linux scripting packet on us to debug and we are all pretty lost. The script is suppose to remove files containing embedded spaces in the file name and I am stuck on the actual rm command. I get "Missing Operand" and I am not sure what to do.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is supposed to delete all filenames in current directory
#+ containing embedded spaces.
# It doesn't work
# Why not?


badname= ls | grep " "

# Try this:
echo "$badname"

rm "$badname"

exit 0
```

Comment: What error or message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need command substition to get the value of `ls | grep " "` into the `badname` variable

Either of the following options will work:

```
badname=`ls | grep " "`
```

or

```
badname=$(ls | grep " ")
```

You can read more about command substitution [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).
Hope this helps

Comment: I get the following error " badname= ls | grep " " "
I don't think there is a problem declaring the variable because the script actually echos the file's to be deleted. I think the problem is with the rm command. Thanks for the response!

Comment: you are telling badname that it equals the text 'ls |grep " "` that is why its echoing it. You are not assigning the variable correctly. You need to have command substitution to get the values of `ls | grep " "` into the variable. Read the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`badname= ls | grep " "` is obviously wrong. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPFILE="tmp.txt"

ls | grep " " > $TMPFILE

cat $TMPFILE | while read -r LINE
do
        rm "$LINE"
done
```

Comment: That works fine, but I don't think that's what he wants since it differs so much from the original. He isn't here so I can't ask him. I think badname= ls | grep " " works fine because it actually echos the bad file names, it just doesn't remove them.